# Typescript type mapping from Interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure correct way to map Interface record value types to correct function type.

```
function stringCompose(): string {
    return ''
}
function numberCompose(): number {
    return 0
}

interface Demo {
    stringVal: string;
    numberVal: number;
}
// mapping type something like <T = any> = (() => T)
type ComposeMapper<T = any> = any;

const builder: ComposeMapper<Demo> = ({
    stringVal: stringCompose,
    numberVal: numberCompose,
});
```

So idea is that when creating builder it check that all Interface keys are in place and someway also do value mappings like Interface "string" => requires "() => string" which compose functions should be filling.
Before I did similar setup, but there was tons of never checks and performance was really bad to solve those so I think there should be much easier way actually to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to create [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) from the interface.

[TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/4w152w)

```ts
function stringCompose(): string {
    return ''
}
function numberCompose(): number {
    return 0
}

interface Demo {
    stringVal: string;
    numberVal: number;
}

type ComposeMapper<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: () =>  T[K]
}

// OK
const builder: ComposeMapper<Demo> = ({
    stringVal: stringCompose,
    numberVal: numberCompose,
});

// Error
const builder1: ComposeMapper<Demo> = ({
//    ~~~~~~~~ Property 'numberVal' is missing in type '{ stringVal: () => string; }' but required in type 'ComposeMapper<Demo>'.(2741)
    stringVal: stringCompose,
});


// Error
const builder2: ComposeMapper<Demo> = ({
    stringVal: numberCompose,
//  ~~~~~~~~~ Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
    numberVal: numberCompose,
});
```